# AWS Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

It's giving me this error even though I have changed the region to eu-west-1b within my script and also within the .aws/config file, my Instance launches in eu-west-1b all the time so unsure why i'm getting this error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import boto3
import time
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-1b')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
keyname = 'key1.pem'
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
user_data = '''#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl start httpd'''

try:
        res = Resp = s3.create_bucket(ACL='private',Bucket='buket2',CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1b'})
        print (res)

try:
        s3_resource.Bucket('buket2').upload_file('image.jpg', 'image.jpg', ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})


try:
        gg = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName='Server', Description = 'Serv1', VpcId='vpc-f3fs4095')

        print (gg)
except Exception as error:
    print (error)

instance = ec2.create_instances(
 ImageId='ami-03odd1b743b23e5d2',
 MinCount=1,
 MaxCount=1,
 InstanceType='t2.nano',
 KeyName = 'key1.pem',
 UserData = user_data, 
 SecurityGroupIds=[sg.group_id] 
)


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time.sleep(600)
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='eu-west-1b')
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/EC2',
            MetricName='CPUUtilization',
            Dimensions=[
                {
                'Name': 'AMIID',
                'Value': 'ami-03odd1b743b23e5d2'
                },
            ],
            StartTime=datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=600),
            EndTime=datetime.now(),
            Period=300,
            Statistics=[
                'Average',
            ],
            Unit='Percent'
        )
print(response)

response = sg.authorize_ingress(
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            "FromPort": 22,
            "ToPort": 22,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "Server"},
            ],
        },
        {
            "FromPort": 80,
            "ToPort": 80,
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "IpRanges": [
                {"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "Description": "Server1"},
            ],
        },
    ],
)
```

I got a long error message but will just include the important bits as most of it just points to files unless you want me to include also.

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://buket2.s3.eu-west-1b.amazonaws.com/"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://buket2.s3.eu-west-1b.amazonaws.com/image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Region** name is `eu-west-1`.

The `b` identifies an **Availability Zone**: `eu-west-1b`

When creating a Resource or Client in boto3, use the Region without the AZ identifier:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-1')
```

To launch an Amazon EC2 instance in a specific Availability Zone, in `create_instances()` or `run_instances()` specify:

```
Placement={'AvailabilityZone': 'eu-west-1b'}
```

or:

```
SubnetId = 'YOUR SUBNET ID'
```

"If not specified, an Availability Zone will be automatically chosen for you based on the load balancing criteria for the Region."

Comment: Ohh that makes sense, I have changed it but when inputting  Placement={'AvailabilityZone': 'eu-west-1b'}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 is the error I get for it, I have create_instances instead of run_instances, also I assume the same applies within my /.aws/config file, I changed to `eu-west-1`

Comment: Ah! It is `resource.create_instances()` and `client.run_instances()`. Similar commands. The `client` method maps to API calls, while the `client` method is more Pythonic. For syntax, see the [`create_instances()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances). If you continue to have an error, please edit your Question to show your current code and the _exact_ error returned.

Comment: Ah that worked fine thanks but unfortunately didn't fix the bigger problem I am having of it not displaying any Datapoints or Average number when called within "get_metric_statistics" on my other post.

Comment: John would you know which command I could add to my create_instance that will enable detailed monitoring for me?

Comment: `Monitoring={'Enabled': True}` -- It's in the boto3 documentation.

Comment: You're a legend John haha, I seen it in there but I mistyped it and then doubted myself so I found this one instead https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.monitor which didn't work as I wanted but your code works perfectly. Thanks once again John